# Dash to .exe utilizing auto-py-to-exe almost there

Tags: python, exe, plotly-dash

I'm working on a Dash app that I would like to be able to distribute via an executable. I have two files "app.py" and "run.py". The "app.py" file has an MS Access database feeding the input/output. "app.py" looks as follows..

```
    import dash
    import dash_html_components as HTML 
    import dash_core_components as dcc 
    import pyodbc
    import dash_table
    import pandas as pd

    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= 
    C:\Users\_file_name_.accdb;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ', conn)

    def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
return html.Table(
    # Header
    [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

    # Body
    [html.Tr([
        html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
    ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
)
    app = dash.Dash()

    app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H4(children='Selection'),
dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown', options=[
    {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df.Name.unique()
], multi=True, placeholder='String...'),
html.Div(id='table-container')
   ])

   @app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('table-container', 'children'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])

   def display_table(dropdown_value):
if dropdown_value is None:
    return generate_table(df)

dff = df[df.Name.str.contains('|'.join(dropdown_value))]
return generate_table(dff)



   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run_server(debug=False)
```

My "run.py" looks as follows.

```
    import os

    os.system('app.py')
```

When I use the auto-py-to-exe tool it works great and the executable runs and delivers the IP address and port number to follow. Paste this into my browser and my app displays flawlessly. My problem arises when this executable file is run on another computer. I get...

```
    'app.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So my question is why does this run locally but not when extended to another computer? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.